# I have service principal account created in azure cloud for azure devops pipeline URL. how do I make a rest call to the url?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, service-principal

I have the follwing url for triggering azure devops pipiline url https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/xxx.This url registered in azure cloud service principal account. previously I used pat token for authentication. now I want to use service principal account. I have clint id and cliend secret of the service principal account. Now How can I make call to the pipeline url through post man or using logic apps. any documentation or something will be really helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curl](https://curl.se/) to make a rest call to the url. You can learn more about curl in the link.

Since you have service principal account created,

**First** you need to request the Access Token.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
-d 'client_id=<client-id>' 
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 
-d 'scope=<scope.default>' 
-d 'client_secret=<client-secret>'
```

**Then** you can call Azure REST API using `Bearer Token` to be authorized:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>' \
    https://{instance}/{collection}/{team-project}/_apis/{area}/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

Comment: am able to get bearer token. but using the token givibg  203 am getting weired text/html

Comment: Error 203 means Non-Authoritative Information. Please check your permissions when accessing to service principal account. And then clear the web browser cache and login in an incognito mode to have a try.